# Can't declare a dead letter exchange using rabbitmqadmin

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to setup a variety of exchanges and queues in RabbitMQ via a script calling rabbitmqadmin. While I can declare a queue, I am not able to find any way to send 'x-dead-letter-exchange' or 'x-dead-letter-routing-key' arguments in the declaration. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, the solution was to do 'rabbitmqadmin export rabbit.config', change the file to include the necessary exchanges, queues and bindings, then 'rabbitmqadmin import rabbit.config'.  Not an optimal solution, but functional.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is possible by specifying JSON in 'arguments' argument:

```
call rabbitmqadmin.py declare queue name=MyQueue arguments={\"x-dead-letter-exchange\":\"MyExchange\",\"x-dead-letter-routing-key\":\"MyRoutingKey\"}
```

Note: this is except from Windows batch file. (on other OS some syntax might be different)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.